# Como converter caracteres especiais?

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema de busca, mas ele não responde muito bem com caracteres especiais, como: `ç`, `ã`, `á`, `ô`, etc.

Então, eu quero que no `input` o usuário digite por exemplo: "União" e que no `GET['nome']` saia mais ou menos assim: `Uni%C3%A3o`.

Já tentei usar o `htmlspecialchars` mas nada acontece!

O motio é, a busca é na API da SuperCell desenvolvedora do Clash of Clans, e a busca só tem êxito quando caracteres especiais são nesse formato!

Comment: Esse formato é o url encoded [RFC 3629](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629). Por quê exatamente quer que seja nesse formato para resolver o problema de busca no seu banco de dados?  (*o negativo não é meu.. mas votei para fechar como "não clara o suficiente")

Comment: Resolvida, é porque a busca é na API da SuperCell desenvolvedora do Clash of Clans, e a busca só tem êxito quando caracteres especiais são nesse formato!

Comment: Ok, retirei o voto e adicionei a explicação ao final da sua pergunta. Das próximas vezes deixe mais claro. E sobre a solução basta usar urlencode(). Não precisa de htmlentities()... Mas ainda poderá ter problemas dependendo do charset. Por isso não confie muito pois pode ocorrer inconsistências.

Comment: obrigado, esse é meu único problema no sistema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a função [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php):

```
$string = "União";
echo htmlentities(urlencode($string)); // Uni%C3%A3o
```